# Whilst integrating an array of data, an axis error occurred. What is the cause and solution of this error?

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of data labeled y_1, for which I want to compute a definite integral of its square value, however, an axis error occurs. I'm using scipy.trapz to integrate the array.

I tried to define the axis as zero, however an axis error stating that the 'axis 0 is out of bounds for an array of dimension 0'

The code is below:

````
    n=4
    hn = np.zeros(n)

    ```
    #n=1
    hn[0] = integrate.trapz(lambda t: y_1**2, 0, 0.3)
    ```
    #n=2
    hn[1] = integrate.trapz(lambda t: y_2**2, 0, 0.3)
    #n=5
    hn[2] = integrate.trapz(lambda t: y_5**2, 0, 0.3)
    #n=20
    hn[3] = integrate.trapz(lambda t: y_20**2, 0, 0.3)
````

The error is:

```
    AxisError: axis -1 is out of bounds for an array of dimension 0
```

Comment: When asking a question, choose the best tags that will help the right people view your question. You tagged you question as integration. However this question has nothing to do with integration (maybe you are doing this a part of an integration project, but that is irrelevant for the question). A much better tag would have been "python", since this is what (I assume) your code is written in. In terms of the actual question, why do you need to use a lambda function? You are trying to integrate y_1 which is already an array.

Comment: @camba1, yeah I realised that I should've used the tag python shortly after posting the question, my bad. I've assumed that the lambda function followed by the t tells the function what it is that I am integrating with respect to (which is the t). I would like to find the integral for each of the values that the array y_1 holds